# Hierarchical Data Traversal and Representation in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, nested, hierarchical-data

I have some hierarchical codes stored in an OrderedDict with keys corresponding to levels of the hierarchy and a list of codes for each level, each child level having relations to a code in the parent level:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

codes_ord_dict = OrderedDict([
    (2, [11]), 
    (3, [111, 112]), 
    (4, [1111, 1112, 1113, 1114, 1119, 1121, 1122, 1123, 1124, 1125, 1129])
])
```

I am trying to get from this form to one such as a nested dictionary or a tree representation of these codes, the former being something like:

```
codes_dict = {
    11: {
        111: {
            1111: {
               ... 
            },
            1112: {
                ...
            },
            1113: {
                ...
            },
            ...
        },
        112: {
            ...
        },
    }
}
```

Mentally I am just not making the programming connection to traverse a level, follow a parent code by pushing onto the next level to build out the children before returning back the way I came and moving on to the next code, while maintaining some kind of record of what relations I have built out and which ones I have not, so there is no repeating. Not really looking for an answer handed to me, but just some strategies for how to approach this. It seems like a solution would involve recursion, but I also have to maintain some state to reference previous level(s) and next level(s).

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your data structure each code contains the information about its parents. So you can first write a function that map the hierarchy of a given code:

```
def code_to_map(code):
    codestr = str(code)
    codemap = [int(codestr[:i]) for i in range(2, len(codestr) + 1)]
    return codemap

print(code_to_map(1111))
# [11, 111, 1111]
```

Then, here is a naive implementation to create the nested dictionary:

```
# create a dictionary to store results

d = {}

# iterate through code list in your ordered dict

for code_list in codes_ord_dict.itervalues():

    # iterate through code in code list

    for code in code_list:

        # initiate new code
        lvl = 0
        parent = d

        # get the code map
        code_map = code_to_map(code)

        # while the dictionary contains the key in the code map
        # child is set as parent and level is incremented

        while parent.has_key(code_map[lvl]):

            parent = parent.get(code_map[lvl])

            lvl += 1

        # Add the new dictionary as the code map does not exist

        parent[code_map[lvl]] = {}

print(d)
# {
#   11: {
#       111: {
#           1111: {},
#           1112: {},
#           1113: {},
#           1114: {},
#           1119: {}
#       },
#       112: {
#           1121: {},
#           1122: {},
#           1123: {},
#           1124: {},
#           1125: {},
#           1129: {}
#       }
#   }
# }
```

This is a naive implementation because it is highly redundant but you got the logic. You actually do not need to iterate through the whole `code_order_dict` but only on the highest level code values (your leaves  `code_order_dict[4]`) as they contains the information about the whole dictionary tree.

Note that I ran this code in python 2.7 but I guess it should run under python 3.

Comment: I appreciate it @Delforge. Your "naive implementation" is well suited for the larger problem case though, as the depth varies across parents and their child nodes. The larger problem has a POSSIBLE 6-levels with 7-digit codes at the 6th level, but again some parent nodes have no children/leaves. So, this is good. I'll post the Python 3 implementation of your answer below, should anybody be curious. I'll also extend the problem out to the 6th-level and post a snippet of the output.

Answer (score 0):

Python 3 implementation of @Delforge's answer

```
def code_to_map(code):
    code_str = str(code)
    code_map = [int(code_str[:i]) for i in range(2, len(code_str) + 1)]
    return code_map

d = {}
for code_list in code_ord_dict.values():
    for code in code_list:
        lvl = 0
        parent = d
        code_map = code_to_map(code)
        while code_map[lvl] in parent:
            parent = parent.get(code_map[lvl])
            lvl += 1
        parent[code_map[lvl]] = {}



from pprint import pprint
pprint(d)
```

---

Output snippet, with 6th level (7-digit) extension

```
{11: {111: {1111: {11111: {111110: {}},
                   11112: {111120: {}},
                   11113: {111130: {}},
                   11114: {111140: {}},
                   11115: {111150: {}},
                   11116: {111160: {}},
                   11119: {111191: {}, 111199: {}}},
            1112: {11121: {111211: {}, 111219: {}}},
            1113: {11131: {111310: {}},
                   11132: {111320: {}},
                   11133: {111331: {},
                           111332: {},
                           111333: {},
                           111334: {},
                           111335: {},
                           111336: {},
                           111339: {}}},
            1114: {11141: {111411: {}, 111419: {}},
                   11142: {111421: {1114211: {}, 1114212: {}, 1114219: {}},
}}
```